# String replace method | Encryption & Decryption

Tags: java, string, encryption, replace

The task is quite simple:

You have just been hired by the CIA as a programmer in the encryption department. Your job is to write a class called Crypto. One method, encrypt, will accept a String that represents the sentence to be encrypted. It will return a String that is the sentence with all v’s (big or small) replaced with “ag’,r”, all m’s (big or small) with “ssad”, all g’s (big or small) with “jeb..w”, and all b’s (big or small) with “dug>?/”.

The class contains another method, decrypt, that accepts a String that represents the sentence to be decrypted. In this method the reverse process described above is performed. It returns a String that is the original sentence before encryption.

My encrypt and decrypt methods work completely fine. It's just that it doesn't encrypt/decrypt how it's supposed to. Here's what a sample test run should look like:

```
Enter a sentence that is to be encrypted: *This is a very big morning.* 
Original sentence = This is a very big morning.
Encrypted sentence = This is a ag',rery dug>?/ijeb..w ssadorninjeb..w. 
Decrypted sentence = This is a very big morning.
```

And here's what *my* output looks like:

```
Enter a sentence that is to be encrypted: This is a very big morning. 
Original sentence = This is a very big morning.
Encrypted sentence = This is a ajedug>?/..w',rery dug>?/ijedug>?/..w ssadorninjedug>?/..w.
Decrypted sentence = This is a very big morning.
```

As you can tell the encrypted sentence doesn't quite match up, and I know why, I just don't know how to fix it.

Here are my methods:

```
String encrypt(String string) {
    return string
            .replace("v", "ag',r").replace("V", "ag',r")
            .replace("m", "ssad").replace("M", "ssad")
            .replace("g", "jeb..w").replace("G", "jeb..w")
            .replace("b", "dug>?/").replace("B", "dug>?/");

}

String decrypt(String string) {
    return string
            .replace("dug>?/", "b")
            .replace("jeb..w", "g")
            .replace("ssad", "m")
            .replace("ag',r", "v");
}
```

Any help/guidance is appreciated!

Comment: You're making several subsequent replacements. So you first replace tye `v` by `ag',r`, and then the `g` by `jeb..w`. But you're only supposed to replace the characters of the original string. Not the characters introduced by a previous replacement. You must do a single pass.

Comment: Your implementation: occurrence of `v` is replaced by `ag',r` (applied to the whole phrase), then the `g` from `ag',r` is replaced by `jeb..w` - this was not expected by original task. Basically, you cannot use `replace` method, you need to iterate over the phrase letter by letter and assemble a new phrase (using for instance StringBuilder).

Comment: @VladimirL. I realise the issue. I just don't know how to fix it. The task specifically says to use string methods and not any external classes. Any ideas?

Comment: @Krish See the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output is wrong because you are replacing `v` with `ag',r`, but then replacing the `g` in `ag',r` with `jeb..w`. You should not replace what is already replaced.

To fix this, you need to start with an empty string, and check each character individually. If it is a `v`, `m`, `g`, or `b`, you append the corresponding gibberish to the string. If it is none of those letters, you append that letter.

Here, I did just that with a `StringBuilder`:

```
private static String encrypt(String s) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    s.chars().forEach(x -> {
        char c = (char)x;
        if (c == 'v' || c == 'V') {
            builder.append("ag',r");
        } else if (c == 'm' || c == 'M') {
            builder.append("ssad");
        } else if (c == 'g' || c == 'G') {
            builder.append("jeb..w");
        } else if (c == 'b' || c == 'B') {
            builder.append("dug>?/");
        } else {
            builder.append(c);
        }
    });
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Edit:

> The task specifically says to use string methods and not any external classes

In that case you can't use a `StringBuilder` and has to use a `String`, but it's the same idea. You just use `+=` to append to it.

You also probably can't use `forEach` either. You need a normal for loop that loops through the indices of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Other method could be (assuming there will be no occurrences of `{1}`, `{2}`, `{3}`, `{4}` markers in the original text) to do something like this:

```
static String encrypt(String string) {
    String encryptedWithNumbers = string
          .replace("v", "{1}")
          .replace("V", "{1}")
          .replace("m", "{2}")
          .replace("M", "{2}")
          .replace("g", "{3}")
          .replace("G", "{3}")
          .replace("b", "{4}")
          .replace("B", "{4}");

     return encryptedWithNumbers
          .replace("{1}", "ag',r")
          .replace("{2}","ssad")
          .replace("{3}", "jeb..w")
          .replace("{4}", "dug>?/");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help! Here's my final (working) code:

```
String encrypt(String string) {

    String s = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
        char c = string.charAt(i);
        if (c == 'v' || c == 'V') {
            s += "ag',r";
        } else if (c == 'm' || c == 'M') {
            s += "ssad";
        } else if (c == 'g' || c == 'G') {
            s += "jeb..w";
        } else if (c == 'b' || c == 'B') {
            s += "dug>?/";
        } else {
            s += c;
        }
    }

    return s;

}
```